# Can i use a raspberry pi zero to read temperature using 4 MAX31865 and corresponding 4 pt100 (3-wire) sensors?

Tags: raspberry-pi, gpio

im a beginner in raspberry pi zero and not able to understand if i can connect 4 MAX31865 modules to the raspberry pi zero.

can i connect all 4 to the same MOSI and MISO pins of the pi?

Comment: Yes, you can connect 4 MAX31865 to Raspberry pi. To do it you need to enable 2 SPI  on raspberry pi and control each module using CE.

Comment: Questions about the Raspberry Pi and its utilities should, instead, be asked on https://https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/